# Prestashop 1.6 add product's manufacturer name in mail template

Tags: email, templates, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'd like to add the product's manufacturer name in the new order e-mail. Customer side and admin side.

So, I'd tried to edit the /mails/fr/order_conf_product_list.tpl file to add a new cell with

> {$product['manufacturer_name']}

but with no chance.

I already tried severals tips from the forum like the following but the cell stayed empty...

https://www.prestash...turer-reference

Any help will be appreciate.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Adrien, have you test the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To realize this operation, you need before add the variable manufacturer

For your test you can edit the file [your_shop]/classes/PaymentModule.php(but the better solution is to use override):

1 - Keep manufacturer object

2 - add the manufacturer object in product_var_tpl

```
foreach ($order->product_list as $product) {
 $manufacturer = new Manufacturer((int)$product['id_manufacturer']);
 ****
  $product_var_tpl = array(
'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
'reference' => $product['reference'],
'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
'unit_price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price, $this->context->currency, false),
'price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price * $product['quantity'], $this->context->currency, false),
'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
'customization' => array()
                        );
```

}

And in your file /mails/fr/order_conf_product_list.tpl

you can use the object 'manufacturer'

```
{$product['manufacturer']->name}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you ! I tried your solution. It didn't work but leads me to resolve my problem.

Comment: In fact you must indicate $product['manufacturer']->name, i edit my answer ;-).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to get the manufacturer's name on the customer mail was, as @timactive wrote, to edit the PaymentModule.php.

**So, to get the manufacturer's name in the customers mails :**

PaymentModule.php :

```
             foreach ($order->product_list as $product) {

                $manufacturer = new Manufacturer((int)$product['id_manufacturer']);

                $product_var_tpl = array(
                    'reference' => $product['reference'],
                    'name' => $product['name'].(isset($product['attributes']) ? ' - '.$product['attributes'] : ''),
                    'unit_price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price, $this->context->currency, false),
                    'price' => Tools::displayPrice($product_price * $product['quantity'], $this->context->currency, false),
                    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                    'customization' => array(),
                    'manufacturer' => $manufacturer->name
                );
```

And than in the order_conf_product_list.html, call the product object like this :

```
            {$product['manufacturer']}
```

It's a part of the solution because I want to add manufacturer's name on the admin new order mail too.

**Add manufacturer's name on the admin new order mail :**

To complete this, I had to edit the MailAlert module like this :

In mailalert.php, in the function "hookActionValidateOrder" :

```
foreach ($products as $key => $product)
    {
        $manufacturer = new Manufacturer($product['id_manufacturer'], $id_lang);
        $items_table .=
            '<tr style="background-color:'.($key % 2 ? '#DDE2E6' : '#EBECEE').';">
                <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;">'.$product['product_reference'].'</td>
                <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;">'.$manufacturer->name.'</td>
                <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em;">
                    <strong><a href="'.$url.'">'.$product['product_name'].'</a>'
                        .(isset($product['attributes_small']) ? ' '.$product['attributes_small'] : '')
                        .(!empty($customization_text) ? '<br />'.$customization_text : '')
                    .'</strong>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em; text-align:right;">'.Tools::displayPrice($unit_price, $currency, false).'</td>
                <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em; text-align:center;">'.(int)$product['product_quantity'].'</td>
                <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em; text-align:right;">'
                    .Tools::displayPrice(($unit_price * $product['product_quantity']), $currency, false)
                .'</td>
            </tr>';
```

And now, to create to cell, go to mailalert/mails/fr/new-order.html and add this line around the line 114 :

```
                <th style="border:1px solid #D6D4D4;background-color:#fbfbfb;font-family:Arial;color:#333;font-size:13px;padding:10px">Marque</th>
```